# Math.random() to array

Tags: javascript

**Question**

I'm looking for a solution to convert a number generated by Math.random() to an array.

**Example**

```
Math.random() returns 0.5353263858705759

I now want to convert this number to [5,3,5,3,2,6,3,8,5,8,7,0,5,7,5,9]
```

**Conditions**

Please note that the first "0." should be left out of the array.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I downvoted it because it shows no research effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the number from `Math.random` to a string, split on the period, pop of the last part, split into an array, and use map if you need to return integers and not strings.

```
Math.random().toString().split('.').pop().split('').map(Number);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MWpHD/1/)

Comment: @Zirak - Oooo, always forget that you can do that !

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Math.random().toString().slice(2).split('')
```

To make each element be an actual number instead of a string

```
Math.random().toString().slice(2).split('').map(Number);
```

Comment: This returns a string in the array

Answer (score 0):

Very easy, simple way:

```
var random = Math.random().toString().split(".")[1].split("").map(Number);
console.log(random)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n6xLN/1/

Edited my answer to put numbers into the array instead of strings.

Comment: it doesn't leave the first 0 out and i think that the OP wants numbers in the array

Comment: It does leave out the Zero before the decimal point, which is exactly as he wanted, but I think you're right about him wanting numbers.

Comment: ah, yes, the `split('.')[1]` picks after the decimal. My excuses.

Comment: Fixed mine to do numbers instead of strings. Although there was already a correct answer above, I figured I'd at least complete mine.

Answer (score -1):

just convert to string then just read as array:

```
var n=Math.random().toString();
for(var i=2;i<n.length;i++)
  alert(n[i]);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: can't underdstand negative vote... code works as asked in question!

Comment: Neckbeards downvote solutions that aren't overly clever. Don't let it bother ya.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but this doesn't return an array as the OP asked for.

Comment: You are right @j08691, i didn't return purely an array but JavaScript is a prototiping language and does not have a type casting system. So I don't see why i need to call additional functions to assure an array when i can access a string with []. Only a comment don't pretend to offend you. :)

Comment: No, I know what you're saying. However some people won't upvote (or just downvote) questions that don't have a complete solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
var n = Math.random() * 10.0;
while (n != 0.0)
{ 
    myArray.push(Math.floor(n));
    n *= 10.0;
}
```